# I got the remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized while i want to login on twitter using Periscope api

Tags: c#, api

[image]

```
InitializeComponent();
LiveCaster.TwitterAPI twit = new LiveCaster.TwitterAPI("a4qT3WqEwYOiJzbKbYkCafpU5", "tduqx9G7479AiKq6fOCzdOGq9TVlt1GQr7AyEHJSLwFteqCfeI");
var url = twit.Authorize();
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
var g = twit.AccessToken("4142795");
LiveCaster.Periscope.Oauth oauth = new LiveCaster.Periscope.Oauth();
oauth.session_key = g.AccessToken;
oauth.session_secret = g.AccessSecret;
oauth.user_id = g.UserID;
oauth.user_name = g.ScreenName;
var u = LiveCaster.Periscope.Authentication(oauth);
MessageBox.Show(u);
```

Comment: what's the question?